# Socket is not disconnecting from server if internet disconnects from device?

Tags: node.js, express, socket.io

I am facing an issue with sockets using socket.io when internet disconnects from device the socket doesn't disconnects from server, but disconnects from server when internet again connected to device it creates a new socket with new id so when i emit on socket, It emit on the previous socket id.

socket version : socket.io@1.3.7
node version : node@v4.4.7